# How to update a table's data in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a table with date filters (*it's a panel with 4 options: day/week/month/year*).  My task is create pagination. After selection of the filter with specific date range, I fetch data from API and save its response to vuex store. I logged everything - fetching and vuex work fine. But when I start to change filters, my table data isn't updating properly - seems like it uses old stored data when new is added. I tried lots of ways to solve it - using a computed property, special counter, etc. How my problem can be solved? Thanks.

```js
<template>
    <div class='page'>
        <h1 class='title'>Bookings</h1>
        <div class='schedule-page classes bookings' :class='{ isActive: isOpenPopup }'>
            <div class='filter-bar-wrapper'>
                <div class='row'>
                    <FilterBar @change='handleFilters' :categories='allCategories' :statuses='bookingClassesStatus' />
                    <button class='button button--primary button--create' @click='handleCreateBooking'
                            v-if='caller !== callerOptions.ADMIN'>
                        Add a new bookings
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='table-wrapper'>
                <p class='title'>{{ today }}</p>
                <table class='bookings-table'>
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID booking</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Time</th>
                        <th>Studio name</th>
                        <th>Client name</th>
                        <th>Class name</th>
                        <th>Categories</th>
                        <th>Points</th>
                        <th>Event creator</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Validate code</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <template>
                        <tr :key='`booking-body-title`' class='empty-row'
                            v-if='this.newBookingsAmount > 0'>
                            <td :style='"padding: 12px 16px 12px 28px; color:" + Styles.BLUE'>New bookings</td>
                        </tr>
                        <template v-for='(booking, index) in this.bookings'>
                                // lots of tr/td
                        </template>
                    </template>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <Pagination :pagesNum='this.pages' @change='handlePaging' />
                            </div>
         </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import moment from 'moment'
import FilterBar from '@/components/schedule/FilterBar'
import STYLES from '@/store/styles'
import bookingStatus from '@/store/modules/bookingStatus'
import Pagination from '@/components/Pagination'
import classStatus from '@/store/modules/classStatus'
import { TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE } from '@/store/modules/admin/config'
import callerOptions from '@/store/modules/admin/bookings/callerOptions'

export default {
    props: {
        currentStudio: {
            type: Object,
        },
        caller: {
            type: String,
            required: true,
            validator: (value) => {
                return Object.values(callerOptions).includes(value)
            },
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            bookings: [],
            newBookingsAmount: 0,
            pages: 0,
            callerOptions: callerOptions,
            mode: '',
            filters: {
                startDate: moment()
                  .startOf('day')
                  .utcOffset(0, true)
                  .toISOString(),
                endDate: moment()
                  .endOf('day')
                  .utcOffset(0, true)
                  .toISOString(),
            },
            bookingClassesStatus: bookingStatus,
            bookingItem: {
                date: null,
                class: '',
                client: '',
                status: '',
                numberOfPoints: null,
                comment: '',
            },
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters([
            'bookingsList',
        ]),
        today() {
            switch (this.mode) {
                case 'day':
                    return moment(this.filters.startDate).format('MMMM D')
                case 'week':
                    return `${moment(this.filters.startDate).utc().format('D.MM')} - ${moment(this.filters.endDate).utc().format('D.MM')}`
                case 'month':
                    return moment(this.filters.startDate).format('MMMM, YYYY')
                case 'year':
                    return moment(this.filters.startDate).format('YYYY')
                default:
                    return 'Invalid date'
            }
        },
    },
    methods: {
        moment,
        ...mapActions([
            'getBookingsList',
            'addBooking',
        ]),
        handleFilters(filters, mode) {
            this.filters = filters
            this.mode = mode
            this.refresh()
        },
        handlePaging(page) {
            const rootElement = document.querySelector('.main-content')
            if (rootElement) {
                rootElement.scrollTo(0, 0)
            }
            switch (this.caller) {
                case callerOptions.ADMIN:
                    this.getBookingsList({
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })
                    break
                case callerOptions.CLIENT:
                    this.getBookingsList({
                        clientId: this.clientInfo.id,
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })
                    break
                case callerOptions.CLASS:
                    this.getBookingsList({
                        classId: this.studioClassesInfo.id,
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })
                    break
                case callerOptions.STUDIO:
                    this.getBookingsList({
                        studioId: this.studiosItemInfo.id,
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })
                    break
                default:
                    break
            }
            this.$router.push({
                name: this.$route.name,
                query: { page: page, mode: this.mode },
            }).catch(() => {
            })
            this.bookings = [...this.bookingsList.filter(item => this.isNew.includes(item.status)), ...this.bookingsList.filter(item => !this.isNew.includes(item.status))]
            this.newBookingsAmount = this.bookingsList.filter(item => this.isNew.includes(item.status)).length > 0 && this.bookingsList !== undefined ? this.bookingsList.filter(item => this.isNew.includes(item.status)).length : 0
            this.pages = this.bookingsPages === undefined ? 1 : this.bookingsPages
        },
        async refresh() {
            switch (this.caller) {
                case callerOptions.ADMIN:
                    await this.getBookingsList({
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: this.$router.currentRoute.query.page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })
                    break
                case callerOptions.CLIENT:
                    await this.getBookingsList({
                        clientId: this.clientInfo.id,
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: this.$router.currentRoute.query.page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })
                    break
                case callerOptions.CLASS:
                    await this.getBookingsList({
                        classId: this.studioClassesInfo.id,
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: this.$router.currentRoute.query.page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })

                    break
                case callerOptions.STUDIO:
                    await this.getBookingsList({
                        studioId: this.studiosItemInfo.id,
                        ...this.filters,
                        page: this.$router.currentRoute.query.page,
                        take: TAKE_ITEMS_PER_PAGE,
                    })
                    break
                default:
                    break
            }
            await this.$router.push({
                name: this.$route.name,
                query: { page: 1, mode: this.mode },
            }).catch(() => {
            })
            
            this.newBookingsAmount = this.bookingsList.filter(item => this.isNew.includes(item.status)).length > 0 && this.bookingsList !== undefined ? this.bookingsList.filter(item => this.isNew.includes(item.status)).length : 0
            this.pages = this.bookingsPages === undefined ? 1 : this.bookingsPages
            this.bookings = this.$store.state.bookings.bookingsList
        },
    },
    async mounted() {
        await this.getClientsList()
        await this.getClassesList()
        await this.getStudiosList()
        this.mode = this.$route.query.mode === undefined ? 'day' : this.$route.query.mode
    },
    watch: {
        filters: {
            handler() {
            },
            deep: true,
        },
        bookings: {
            handler() {
            },
            deep: true,
        }
    },
    components: {
        FilterBar,
        Pagination,
    },
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. My solution was to add undefined validation inside rows